# The convergence of a sub-additive sequence of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

In solving Brezis' *exercise 6.23.2*, I have to verify that

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sub-additive sequence of real numbers, i.e., $a_{n+m} \le a_n + a_m$ for all $n,m \ge 1$. Then $\lim_n \frac{a_n}{n} = \inf_n \frac{a_n}{n}$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you please have a check on it?

---

It's clear that $\alpha := \inf_n \frac{a_n}{n} \le \liminf_n \frac{a_n}{n}$. It remains to prove that $\limsup_n \frac{a_n}{n} \le \alpha$. Fix $m \ge 1$. It suffices to prove that $\limsup_n \frac{a_n}{n} \le \frac{a_m}{m}$.

For each $n \ge 1$,  we write $n=m q+r$ with $m$ being the divisor, $q$ the quotient and $r$ the remainder. Then $0 \le r <m$. By sub-additivity of $(a_n)$, we have $a_n \le q a_m + a_r$ and thus
$$
\frac{a_n}{_n} \le \frac{mq}{n} \frac{a_m}{m} + \frac{a_r}{n}.
$$

On the other hand, $\frac{mq}{n} = \frac{n-r}{n}$ and thus $\lim_n \frac{mq}{n} =1$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\limsup_n \frac{a_n}{n} &\le \limsup_n\frac{mq}{n} \frac{a_m}{m} + \lim_n \frac{a_r}{n} \\
&= \frac{a_m}{m}.
\end{align*}
$$

The claim then follows.

Comment: The $r$ depends on $n$, however $0\leq r<m$ ans so, $\frac{|a_r|}{n}\leq\frac{\max(|a_j|:0\leq j\leq m)}{n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$.